# Minimal $x$ for which $\phi(k) > n$ for all $k > x$

Tags: number-theory, special-functions, totient-function, arithmetic-functions

It's well-known that
$$
\liminf_n\frac{\varphi(n)\log\log n}{n}=e^{-\gamma}
$$
and there exists an effective version
$$
\varphi(n)>\frac {n}{e^\gamma\log\log n+\frac{3}{\log\log n}} 
$$
valid for $n\ge3.$ Of course the RHS is increasing and so has an inverse, but I would like to know if there is an explicit formula (giving a tight bound) with
$$
\varphi(f(n))>n.
$$

Is this too much to ask?

Comment: Would you mind and tell up what $\varphi$ is?

Comment: Euler's totient function, https://oeis.org/A000010.

Comment: Are you asking whether there is readily available (non-asymptotic) inverse bound?  Or are you looking for something tighter than what can be extracted from the lower bound on $\phi(n)$?

Comment: @ErickWong: Something more explicit than "the inverse of n/(e^gamma ...)" but hopefully not much weaker than that. Something that's asymptotically the right size, at least -- $e^\gamma n\log\log n.$

Comment: The function is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A139795 but no estimates are given. It is closely related to http://oeis.org/A137315 and maybe the references at that sequence would be helpful.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I just need the smooth version, the much harder question solved at A139795 is too computationally intensive for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume we're going to find a bound of the form $n<f(n) < n\log n$ (at least for $n$ large enough) so
$$
\begin{align}
\log n < \log f & < \log n+\log\log n\\
\log\log n < \log \log f & < \log(\log n + \log\log n)\\
\end{align}
$$
Then from your bound $\phi(f)<n$ requires that
$$
f < n \left(e^\gamma\log\log f+3/\log\log f\right) \\
f < n \log\log f (e^\gamma+3/(\log\log f)^2) \\
f < n\log(\log n + \log\log n)\left(e^\gamma+3/(\log\log n)^2\right)
$$
So 
$$
N>n\log(\log n + \log\log n)\left(e^\gamma+3/(\log\log n)^2\right)
\Rightarrow \phi(N)>n
$$
I guess there may be a slightly better version, since the bound for $n=10^7$ gives $6.38\times 10^7$, whereas the last $N$ with $\phi(N)\le 10^7$ seems to be $58198540$.